# Smooth involutions on homotopy 11-spheres or diffeomorphism classification of homotopy projective 11-space

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, involutions

Does anyone know if smooth fixed point free involutions on homotopy 11-spheres have been studied? Or equivalently, is something known about the diffeomorphism classification of homotopy $\mathbb{R}P^{11}$?

And more generally, homotopy (4k-1)-spheres and homotopy $\mathbb{R}P^{4k-1}$?

Comment: I suggest looking at López de Medrano, "Involution on Manifolds", and seeing if you can piece together a full answer for $\Bbb{RP}^{11}$ from the results in Chapter VI. The author outlines what the answer will look like in the general case.

Comment: @MikeMiller I know this reference, but the only thing I could find for dimension 11 is the existence of smooth involutions on every homotopy 11-sphere (V.6.2, I suppose you were referencing the comment on p.72).

Comment: The results of IV.3, V.2, and V.7 combine to show that you only need to determine the set of possible normal invariants (and then the set of homotopy smoothings will be this times $\Bbb Z$ times $\Bbb Z/992$; this uses that all ). The normal invariants are the inverse image of zero in the map $[\Bbb{RP}^{11}, G/O] \to \Bbb Z/2 = L_{11}(\Bbb Z/2)$. What remains is to calculate this set of homotopy classes, and the surgery obstruction. You're right that this isn't contained in de Medrano's book; I don't know before a literature search whether this is known. You see already how complicated it is.

Comment: Apologies if I am telling you things you already know.

Comment: @MikeMiller I did in fact already know this, so I guess I wanted to see if somebody either knew where this classification is completed (i.e. the normal invariants are computed) or if there was another approach. But thanks for the summary anyway!